# Vaadin-Unable to update grid container on combobox value change

Tags: combobox, grid, containers, vaadin, selection

I am using vaadin 7.7.7

In a grid i have a combobox as an edited item in one of the columns
as

```
grid.addColumn("columnProperty").setEditorField(combobox);
```

I need to update a property/cell in same row based on the combobox selection change

My issue is , the selection change event triggers twice, once when the combobox in clicked and second when the selection value is changed. But the updated value in next cell gets reflected on UI only first time.
Below is the code written . Any solutions?

```
Combobox.addValueChangeListener(new ValueChangeListener()
@Override
public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {

// below line works only first time when the combobox is clicked,but i want 
//it when the item in the combobox is changed

gridContainer.getContainerProperty(editedRow,"editedColumProperty").setValue("ValueTobeUpdated");}
   });
```

Need to update the unit column on combobox change in edited mode(before saving)

Refer below link for image

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAh5t.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get value change events even when the field gets value that it should show to the user. In order to get event that indicates that the user has accepted the input you should use field group ([setEditorFieldGroup](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Grid.html#setEditorFieldGroup-com.vaadin.data.fieldgroup.FieldGroup-)).

From Book of Vaadin [example for grid editing](https://github.com/vaadin/book-examples/blob/master/src/com/vaadin/book/examples/component/grid/GridEditingExample.java):

```
grid.getColumn("name").setEditorField(nameEditor);

FieldGroup fieldGroup = new FieldGroup();
grid.setEditorFieldGroup(fieldGroup);
fieldGroup.addCommitHandler(new CommitHandler() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8378742499490422335L;

    @Override
    public void preCommit(CommitEvent commitEvent)
           throws CommitException {
    }

    @Override
    public void postCommit(CommitEvent commitEvent)
           throws CommitException {
        Notification.show("Saved successfully");
    }
});
```

*Edit*

I assume that you want to connect Parameter and Unit comboboxes. I would do that with this kind of value change lister

```
BeanItemContainer container = new BeanItemContainer<>(
        Measurement.class,
        measurements);
Grid grid = new Grid(container);
grid.setEditorEnabled(true);
ComboBox parameterComboBox = new ComboBox();
ComboBox unitComboBox = new ComboBox();
parameterComboBox.addItems(Parameter.Pressure, Parameter.Temperature, Parameter.Time);
parameterComboBox.addValueChangeListener(v -> setUnits(parameterComboBox, unitComboBox));
grid.getColumn("parameter").setEditorField(parameterComboBox);
grid.getColumn("unit").setEditorField(unitComboBox);
```

Units could be updated like this. I think you need to preserve current value and set it back if you replace available items in the combobox.

```
private void setUnits(ComboBox parameterComboBox, ComboBox unitComboBox) {
    Object currentValue = unitComboBox.getValue();
    List<String> units = unitsForParameter(parameterComboBox.getValue());
    unitComboBox.removeAllItems();
    unitComboBox.addItems(units);
    if (units.contains(currentValue)) {
        unitComboBox.setValue(currentValue);
    } else {
        unitComboBox.setValue(null);
    }
}

private List<String> unitsForParameter(Object value) {
    if (value == null) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    } else if (value == Parameter.Pressure) {
        return asList("Pascal", "Bar");
    } else if (value == Parameter.Temperature) {
        return asList("Celcius", "Kelvin");
    } else if (value == Parameter.Time) {
        return asList("Second", "Minute");
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unhandled value: " + value);
    }
}
```

Comment: but addComitHandler fires on save click. I need to update other cell based on combobox change value before saving(in edited mode). Refer the image in the question.